# Rspec automatically run file which are having _spec suffix but if I want to other file also which does not have _spec then what should i do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, tdd

In rails I need that when I run rspec . it will consider all file which are inside the spec directory. As of now it is considering only those file which is having _spec suffix. How can I do it , any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Why can't you rename the files? Sounds like you might be trying to solve the wrong problem.

Comment: Yes you are right, But just want to know how we can achieve it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to include other file name suffixes, you can pass a param when running `rspec` as shown in the [docs here](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-7/docs/command-line/pattern-option), like this, to include files ending in `_spec.rb` and `_test.rb`.

```
rspec -P "**/*_test.rb,**/*_spec.rb"
```

You can also include this param in a `.rspec` file in the root of your project that passes this pattern in automatically, like this in the `.rspec` file:

```
--pattern "**/*_test.rb,**/*_spec.rb"
```